# When I remove app the code stops working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following code for angularjs working perfecly:

[Working fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XmPfQ78vRjSrxE0Tt3B?p=preview)

But as soon as I use the above code without defining app I get an error and autocomplete stops working:

here is the code with jfiddle link:

```
function ctrl($scope) {
$scope.availableTags = [],
$scope.complete = function() {
   /* return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;*/
    availableTags= [
                          "ActionScript",
                          "AppleScript",
                          "Asp",
                          "BASIC",
                          "C",
                          "C++",
                          "Clojure",
                          "COBOL",
                          "ColdFusion",
                          "Erlang",
                          "Fortran",
                          "Groovy",
                          "Haskell",
                          "Java",
                          "JavaScript",
                          "Lisp",
                          "Perl",
                          "PHP",
                          "Python",
                          "Ruby",
                          "Scala",
                          "Scheme"
                        ];
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#txt").autocomplete({
            source: $scope.availableTags,
        });

    });
    //return $scope.availableTags;
}
```

}

Here is jfiddle link:

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/ozujuzvh/4/)

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The `app` declaration is what tells Angular what code to load. It matches the `ng-app` directive in your html. Without that match, angular can't know what code you're trying to run.

Comment: But if you change the code to something simple like : function namesController($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
}   and for html :  <div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script src="personController.js"></script> though we do not have app defined it works perfectly !!!